# Android studio java language is not listed in build configuration languages

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2. I have started a new project and chooses empty view activity. all I can see is kotlin DSL and Groovy but java is not listed.
any idea why ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at the Gradle language?  Gradle is never written in Java, and Android apps are never written in Groovy.  But Gradle scripts are written in Kotlin DSL and Groovy.

Comment: Also, you don't have to choose Kotlin or Java.  The two are 100% interoperable.  Kotlin can call Java and Java can call Kotlin.  So you don't need to choose between them-  just create a new Java file or new Kotlin file as desired

Comment: Are you looking Language or Build configuration language?

Comment: @ayushimaheshwari build configuration.